# How to add days based on input value in each rows of the dynamic table using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

[image]My problem is, I have to add days based on the input given in the text box for all the rows of the dynamic table.
I have added days for 2 row but 3,4... row displaying the value of 2 row.
Now I want to add days in the 3rd row and goes on..........

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        $("body").on("focusout",function(){

            var trLength=$('body #appendRows tr').length;
            for (var i = 1; i <trLength; i++) {
                $('#appendRows tr:nth-child(2)').remove();
            }


            var val  = $(".ND").val();
             var m  =  $("#follow_Date").val();



                    var j = $("#Amount").val();
                    var k = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;
                    var date = new Date(k);
                    var newdate = new Date(date);
                    newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() +
                        parseInt(m));

                    var dd = newdate.getDate();
                    var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
                var y = newdate.getFullYear();
                 var someFormattedDate = mm+ '/' + dd + '/' + y;

            var i=1;
            for(i==1;i<val;i++){
                var html = $("#appendRows tr:first-child").clone();
                html.find("input").val("");
                html.find('input[name^="Sno"]').val(i+1);
              html.find('input[name^="Date"]').val(someFormattedDate + parseInt(m));
                 html.find('input[name^="Amount"]').val(j);
                 console.log(date, i, someFormattedDate)
                $('#appendRows').append(html);
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

This is a javascript code for creating table..............[image]

This is my dynamic table,it will created based on input value in the text field...

```
<table class='table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-xxs' id="cartGrid">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>

                                    <th>Sno</th>
                                    <th >Date</th>
                                    <th >Amount</th>
                                    <th >Bank Name</th>
                                    <th >Chqamt</th>
                                    <th >Payable</th>
                                    <th>Bank1</th>
                                    <th >Chqamt1</th>
                                    <th >Payable1</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="appendRows">
                                <tr>

                                <td ><input style="width:40px" type="text" class="form-control" name="Sno[]" value="1" id="Sno"></td>

                                <td><input style="width:80px" type="text" class="form-control" name="Date[]" value="" id="Date"></td>

                                <td> <input style="width:70px" type="text" class="form-control" name="Amount[]" value="" id="Amount"></td>

                                <td ><input style="width:80px" type="text" class="form-control" name="Bankname[]" id="Bankname"></td>

                                <td ><input style="width:80px" type="text" class="form-control" name="Chqamt[]" id="Chqamt"></td>

                                <td ><input style="width:80px" type="text" class="form-control" name="Payable[]" id="Payable"></td>

                                <td ><input style="width:80px" type="text" class="form-control" name="Bank1[]" id="Bank1"></td>

                                <td ><input style="width:80px" type="text" class="form-control" name="Chqamt1[]" id="Chqamt1"></td>

                                <td ><input style="width:80px" type="text" class="form-control" name="Payable1[]" id="Payable1"></td>



                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

This is table code..................

```
    <label class="col-lg-1 control-label" id="pd">Due Start:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-xs datepicker-dates Dues" placeholder="Due Start Date&hellip;" id="txtDate" name="TDDate" value="">
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

</div>

                        </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <fieldset>
                                <label class="col-lg-1 control-label" id="pd">Mode:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <input type="number" id="follow_Date" placeholder="Mode" name="TMode" class="form-control input-xs Mode">
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

</div>
```

This is due start and mode text box code.........

Comment: you want to create 30 rows dynamically for the full year, right? can't undesrtand the question, can you please add html part of the project, so i can reproduce your code

Comment: try this..date=date.getTime()+30*24*60*60*1000;
var newDate = new Date(date);

Comment: no sir, rows created based on input value (i.e if i give 3 in the text box, 3 rows automatically create that is not a problem now) my problem is, see the picture i have attached in first row of "date" columns display the text box value and it adds 30 days in second rows and third row and 4 th row 30 days are not added..... exisiting value is displaying

Comment: @line88 i have add a second pic

Comment: "due start" date is display on first row and second row value is added by 30 and 3,4 row is not added by 30

Comment: @xTroy it is not working............

Comment: aaah! you just want to SUM 30 days to the `date` and show it in the `due start` col? and you are creating dynamic rows with that `due start` col, right?

Comment: s sir......... :) dynamic rows is created based on input fields given on the "mode"

Comment: try `console.log(date, i, someFormattedDate)` inside the loop where you append `html` and see what you get

Comment: sir i have made mistake  in the question..

Comment: What the value is given in "Mode" text box that value is add in the existing date and through out the rows of date column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

```js
$(function(){
  $('#txtDate, #follow_Date, .ND').keyup( function () {

    // Clear rows
    var trLength = $('body #appendRows tr').length;
    for (var i = 1; i <trLength; i++) {
      $('#appendRows tr:nth-child(2)').remove();
    }

    var val = (!$(".ND").val()) ? 1 : val = $(".ND").val();
    var m  =  $("#follow_Date").val();
    var j = $("#Amount").val();
    var k = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;
    var currentDate = moment(k); 
    
    for (var i = 0, len = val; i < val; ++i) {
      var newdate = currentDate.add(parseInt(m), 'days');
      var html = $("#appendRows tr:first-child").clone();
      html.find("input").val("");
      html.find('input[name^="Sno"]').val(i+1);
      html.find('input[name^="Amount"]').val(j);
      // I format this to make it clear
      html.find('input[name^="Date"]')
          .val(newdate.format('YYYY/MM/DD'));
      $('#appendRows').append(html);
    }
    
    // Remove that first row
    $("#appendRows tr:first-child").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<div>
<label class="col-lg-1 control-label" id="pd">Due Start:</label>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-xs datepicker-dates Dues" placeholder="Due Start Date&hellip;" id="txtDate" name="TDDate" value="2018/12/12">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="form-group">
<fieldset>
<label class="col-lg-1 control-label" id="pd">Mode:</label>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4">
<input type="number" id="follow_Date" placeholder="Mode" name="TMode" class="form-control input-xs Mode" value="30">
</div>
</div>
</div>

<label class="col-lg-1 control-label" id="pd">Rows:</label>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4">
<input type="number" class="ND" placeholder="Number of rows" name="TMode" class="form-control input-xs Mode" value="10">
</div>
</div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</div>
</div>

<table class='table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-xxs' id="cartGrid">
<thead>
<tr>

<th>Sno</th>
<th >Date</th>
<th >Amount</th>
<th >Bank Name</th>
<th >Chqamt</th>
<th >Payable</th>
<th>Bank1</th>
<th >Chqamt1</th>
<th >Payable1</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="appendRows">
<tr>

<td ><input style="width:40px" type="text" class="form-control" name="Sno[]" value="1" id="Sno"></td>

<td><input style="width:80px" type="text" class="form-control" name="Date[]" value="" id="Date"></td>

<td> <input style="width:70px" type="text" class="form-control" name="Amount[]" value="" id="Amount"></td>

<td ><input style="width:80px" type="text" class="form-control" name="Bankname[]" id="Bankname"></td>

<td ><input style="width:80px" type="text" class="form-control" name="Chqamt[]" id="Chqamt"></td>

<td ><input style="width:80px" type="text" class="form-control" name="Payable[]" id="Payable"></td>

<td ><input style="width:80px" type="text" class="form-control" name="Bank1[]" id="Bank1"></td>

<td ><input style="width:80px" type="text" class="form-control" name="Chqamt1[]" id="Chqamt1"></td>

<td ><input style="width:80px" type="text" class="form-control" name="Payable1[]" id="Payable1"></td>



</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you sir @parndepu but i have edited question. please  help me for that question

Comment: I hope it may help. Good luck.

Comment: Updated. Please check this out. Thanks

Comment: sir first row is empty

Comment: the same problem is i have occured

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184465/discussion-between-teddy-and-parndepu).

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments, use `keyup` event on the `Mode` input to add rows when you enter number into the `Mode` input...and just add 0 days to the first occurence of the date

```js
function add() {
  var val = $(".Mode").val();
  var currentdate = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;
  currentdate = getDueDate(currentdate, 0);
  
  $("#appendRows tr").not('.master-row').remove(); // remove previous rows (reset the table)

  for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
    
    var someFormattedDate = formatDate(currentdate);
    var html = $("#appendRows tr:first-child").clone();
    html.find("input").val("");
    html.find('input[name^="Sno"]').val(i + 1);
    html.find('input[name^="Date"]').val(someFormattedDate);
    html.removeClass('master-row');
    $('#appendRows').append(html);
    currentdate = getDueDate(currentdate, val);
  }
}

function formatDate(date) {
  var dd = date.getDate();
  var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var y = date.getFullYear();
  return mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y;
}

function getDueDate(from, days) {
  var fromDate = new Date(from);
  var dueDate = new Date(from);
  dueDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + days * 1);

  return dueDate;
}
add();
$('.Mode').on('keyup', function() {
  add();
});
```

```css
.master-row {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
the data
<div>
  <input type="text" class="Mode" value="3">
  <input type="text" id="txtDate" value="12/29/2018">
</div>

<div style="height:20px">

</div>
the table
<table id="appendRows">
  <tr class="master-row">
    <td><input type="text" name="Sno"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Date"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To hide "master-row" i would do something like this, also its better to break code to the separate functions

Comment: the next row cannot add the date 2nd row value is displaying

Comment: sorry, didn't understand you, do you mean the row with the empty values?

first one is the data inputs, second row is empty because it the master row from whch you make clone (you can keep master row always hidden)

Comment: check the second snippet

Comment: the date is not adding same date value is displaying

Comment: 2 row of date column add by 3 and 3rd add by 3 by 2nd row date,

Comment: Ahh Finally ! you want to sum 3 days for the every row from the prev one? e.g: 11/29/2018 in the second will be 12/2/2018 in the 3rd will be 12/5/2018, right?

Comment: can you understand what i am saying @line88

Comment: :) check it now

Comment: to the first row 30 days added, to the next rows `Mode` val from the first row

Comment: without button i need a code when i entered mode value the table is created without clicking button.......

Comment: no sir first row display the value of the text box itself. it should not add by 30

Comment: i have edited my question and code.please you can see that code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184457/discussion-between-line88-and-teddy).

Comment: sir already i have one row in the table so the first and second display the same value.please see my edited questiion

Comment: i have two text box one for creating dynamic table, another one for adding date.